# How can I make rhythmbox/gpodder download podcasts into a single folder?

Tags: rhythmbox, podcast, gpodder

I listen to podcast on my android phone. Since I only listen to podcasts, I want to play a single folder. I am using folderplayer which cannot go into subfolders (at least, I didn't find how to make it do so).

Also, going through the available podcatchers and didn't like any of them.

So, I want to copy all the files which rhythmbox/gpodder downloaded and into a single folder on my device. Is it possible?

I can write a script that does so. But I want to be sure there is no other way first.

Comment: Where do you want to do this, in your android phone?

Comment: I want to copy the files to my android device

Comment: From where you want to copy them? Exactly what you try to do?

Comment: @Braiam Both program download the podcast to the local directory and place each podcasts in its own subfolder (one folder per podcast). I want to copy all the audio files to a **single** directory on my android device. I don't want to retain the original folder structure.

Comment: The problem is that I don't see where Ubuntu comes into play here.